# form with inner two vertical scoller

Tags: jquery, css, sass, css-selectors

In this form there is common form in which because of modal content height exceed there will be overflow and outer scroll will come.

there are 2-3 margin and padding property if i will remove that property there are no problem but form look ugly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PFp6.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGwIo.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code.